# i have a error when save data in to mysql work bench

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

Here is my MYSQL database:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZcTV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6xqs.png)

and here is code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCr6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofWfy.png)

and Error message:
run:
thg 12 03, 2020 9:45:51 CH program.StudentModify insert
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Number) values('sdsdsd','Male',23,'sdsdsd','232323')' at line 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1915)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1254)
at program.StudentModify.insert(StudentModify.java:79)
at program.StudentJFrame.btSaveActionPerformed(StudentJFrame.java:260)
at program.StudentJFrame$3.actionPerformed(StudentJFrame.java:111)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should write 'Phone Number' in one word like PhoneNumber.

Or write `Phone Number` with backticks around the words in the insert statement - in the create statement you used backticks around the field names.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Number) 
values('sdsdsd','Male',23,'sdsdsd','232323')'
```

'Number is probably the second part of 'Phone Number'.

Answer (score 0):

You have Phone Number in your SQL query.

In your code, you open and close the connection every time the method is used
You can move the connection and the close-in separate methods

For example :

```
    public Connection connect() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASSWORD);

        return connection;
    }

  public void disconnect(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try instead of:

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentmanagement?&useSSL=false"

Try:

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentmanagement?autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false"